# Finding Streamlines in Region bounded flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Liquid is streaming steadily and irrotationally in 2D in the region bounded by one branch of of a hyperbola and its minor axis. Find streamlines.
I am unable to proceed in such a question of flow bounded in a region.
What should be the approach? Should we try to find complex potential and then the streamlines?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a coordinate system with the hyperbola and minor axis as your boundaries.
Write down the equation of the hyperbola in your coordinate system. The equation of a hyperbola in standard form is:
(x-h)^2/a^2 - (y-k)^2/b^2 = 1

where (h,k) is the center of the hyperbola, a is the distance from the center to the vertices, and b is the distance from the center to the co-vertices.

Determine the complex potential for the flow in this region. This can be done by finding a function Phi(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) that satisfies the Laplace equation:
∂^2Φ/∂x^2 + ∂^2Φ/∂y^2 = 0

where u(x,y) is the velocity potential and v(x,y) is the stream function.

Once you have the complex potential, you can find the stream function by taking the imaginary part:
v(x,y) = Im[Φ(z)]

To find the streamlines, you can plot the level curves of the stream function. These are the curves where v(x,y) is constant.
Note: Since the flow is steady, irrotational, and incompressible, the complex potential is a holomorphic function. This means that it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations, which can help you find it.

Also, if you are having trouble finding the complex potential, you can try using conformal mapping to transform the region into a simpler one, where it is easier to find the complex potential.